# Influencing the GC order (keeping an object alive)

Tags: c#, memory-management, garbage-collection

Following Situation: I've got a singleton-class which is loading a C-DLL internally (let's call it Foo), and also constructs elements which are accessing the same DLL (also in the d'tor) - it's name shall be Bar.

The problem now is: When I close the Application, the GC sometimes destroys Foo before all the created Bar instances are destroyed. The result is undesireable: Foo is a nice class and cleans up after itself, including closing the DLL. Bar needs to access a DLL function on closing - leading to an access violation.

So the Question is: how to resolve this Issue? My initial approach was: Since Foo is creating all Bar instances, just put every created Bar instance into a List (which is a member of Foo) to create some references, the idea obviously: The GC might destroy all the references before destroying the object holding it. Unfortunately, this isn't the case (probably because of possible circular references) Maybe there is some strong reference which can force this behaviour.

So... any ideas?

Addendum:

The idea of using IDisposeable seems great. One particular issue comes to mind: I don't want to encapsule the created `Bar` object in `try` or `using` blocks (since I want to have it available for multiple independent functions).
So my approach would be to still keep track of the created `Bar` objects inside the `Foo` singleton and just call `Dispose` for each `Bar` on `Foo` destructor, as well as calling it individually on each `Bar` destructor. In my particular implementation, this seems to be fine, as I'm making sure that the functionality is only called once (so either `Bar` is destructed first then it's ok since `Foo` is still up, or `Bar` is destructed last, then the critical functionality isn't going to be called again).
Still...this approach doesn't seem very clean, let's see following example:

```
Bar bar = null;

void Func1()
{
  if(bar == null) bar = Foo.Instance.CreateBar();
  bar.DoSomething();
}

void Func2()
{
  if(bar == null) bar = Foo.Instance.CreateBar();
  bar.Dispose();
}
```

If I'm calling only `Func1` this fine. However...calling `Func1` after calling `Func2` might cause issues (since `DoSomething` requires the object not to be disposed). Granted: I can still add some security checks, but somehow this doesn't seem clean to me.

Are there any better practises?

Maybe one additional point regarding the usecase: This is all part of a library (a DLL wrapper actually) where I've got a Singleton (which holds access to the DLL) which is used to create specific objects. These objects are used inside the DLL using handles. To benefit the user experience, I decided not to expose the handles towards the user but a specific class instead (which is keeping the handle internally, the usage then is more straight forward).

So instead of

```
uint handle = Foo.Instance.CreateObject();
Foo.Instance.DoSomething(handle);
Foo.Instance.Destroy(handle);
```

I have s.th. like:

```
Bar bar = Foo.Instance.CreateBar();
bar.DoSomething();
//I don't want the user to care about destruction, which is actually causing my initial problem
```

Maybe this architecture is flawed, but I honestly can't think of a better way (actually, I think this is a good architecture)

Comment: Bar should be `IDisposeable`, if you used `using` statements on all Bar returned from Foo then the Bar instances would be cleaned up before it started GCing Foo.

Comment: **Are there any better practises?** Yes, `IDisposable`. Don't let GC handle your cleanup, take responsibility of the cleanup yourself, dispose of the objects before letting them go, then you won't have any such problems.

Comment: In your Func1 and Func2 examples. That class that you show that contains Func1, Func2 and bar should also be marked `IDisposeable` then dispose of `bar` when the dispose method is called on it. You can still do lazy loading of `bar`, just check for null in the `Dispose()` method before you call `bar.Dispose()`

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to solve a problem that the CLR refuses to tackle, strong hint that there's trouble looming on the horizon.  Finalization order is non-deterministic, you can't force it either.  You'll have to reference-count yourself to know when no remaining Foo or Bar objects remain.  Increment it in their constructors, decrement it in their finalizers, cleanup when it reaches 0.

Note that this does mean that the clean-up code cannot be part of Foo or must be static since it might be a Bar that's the one that counts the reference count down to 0.

Watch out for "thrashing", the client code repeatedly creating a Foo and letting it die again, you'll constantly load and unload the DLL.  Maybe leaving the DLL resident isn't that bad after all :)  The pinvoke plumbing certainly doesn't think it is.

Comment: Foo is actually a singleton (because it might be fatal to reload the DLL - I can't really know as I'm using 3rd party DLLs).
I like the idea about reference counts (I'm more a C++ guy where things like this are more widely used) - but I can't really think about a way where this is helping me...
I call the c'tor only once, the d'tor only once, also the GC doesn't seem to care about any kind of references. When I close the Application...it just destroys everything in a random order (even if I manage to keep the references). Making the user to clean up his objects doesn't seem the C# way to me.